# How can I make the height of table rows become even, after I add the dividing line?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

Dear experienced friends, I met a question when I draw the table in LaTex. Suppose I want to draw a simple table as follows. We can see that the gaps between each line are evenly distributed. However, after I added the dividing line with `\hline` into the table, I found this **dividing line is always closer to the row below**.

May I ask is there any way that I can make the gap of rows evenly distributed again? To be more specific, I hope the heights between `A->B`,`B->Dividing line`,`Dividing line->D`,`D->E` become same. Can we achieve that?

Thank you so much in advance.

[image]

```
% Here is my code

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l | l | p{5cm}}
\hline
 Name & ID & Description \\
\hline 
 $\mathit{A}$ & 1 & This is A \\
 $\mathit{B}$ & 2 & This is B \\
\hline
 $\mathbf{D}$ & 4 & This is D\\
 $\mathbf{E}$ & 5 & This is E\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility would be the `booktabs` package.  One feature to know about, however, is that `booktabs` has strong opinions about how tables should look.  One of those opinions is that you should never use vertical lines in a table.  As such, vertical lines do not work well in tables with `booktabs`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l l p{5cm}}
\toprule
 Name & ID & Description \\
\midrule
 $\mathit{A}$ & 1 & This is A \\
 $\mathit{B}$ & 2 & This is B \\
\midrule
 $\mathbf{D}$ & 4 & This is D\\
 $\mathbf{E}$ & 5 & This is E\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: image output]

Comment: Your answer perfectly solves my question. Thank you so much for your answer, @Teepeemm!